# Multiple AJAX calls are causing the server to hang, for exactly sixty seconds

Tags: php, ajax, browser

I have a door designer that loads in options based on what the user picks. When the page the designer sits on initially loads it makes a series of AJAX calls (25 in total one for each option) to obtain JSON objects that contain lists of choices for each option.

My problem is that the AJAX calls hang, for about a minute, almost every time. This is what Chrome's network panel shows:

[image]

I do not understand why the first six calls hang. I know that there is a limit of six calls from a browser at a time, but as each resolves the next query should be passed until they are all complete?

The call is made from a JS file, inside a document ready function which aims at (for example) http://website.name/api.php/api/products/get/door_colour

This call hits the api.php page and is split into three components, the page/class that handles the query (products), the function name (get) and the thing we're looking for (door_colour).

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

// Include Core Classes
foreach (glob("classes/*.php") as $filename) {
    include($filename);
}

// Get URL Segments
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$url = str_replace("api.php","",$url);
$url = str_replace("//","",$url);

// Split Segments
$segments = explode("/",$url);

$root = $segments[0];
$class = $segments[1];
$method = $segments[2];

// Create Parameters Array
$parameters = $segments;
unset($parameters[0]);
unset($parameters[1]);
unset($parameters[2]);

// Rebase Array
$parameters = array_values($parameters);

$instance = new $class($parameters);
$output = $instance->$method();

$json = json_encode($output);

echo $json;
```

The products.php file is too long to post in it's entirety but essentially it boils down to:

```
public function get($option)
{
    //query the db
    $results = pdo::query('select * where option = :option');

    //create an empty array to be returned as json later
    $data = array();

    //loop through the results
    foreach($results as $result){
        //check if there is an image for the option
        if(file_exists($result->filename)){
            //add the option to the data to be returned
            $data[] = $results
        }
    }
    //echo the data as json
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I'm not able to see anything that might account for the initial hang. The only thing I have come across so far is PHP session locks as the api.php file does start a session each time, which is not closed that I can see, but the session isn't actually used at all so I'm not convinced.

If I use Chromes network panel to 'replay XHR' each of the original six that hangs returns instantly. The amount of data returned is tiny, 15KB at most.

What could be causing the AJAX calls to hang?

Answer (score 4):

When using a session, PHP will only process one request at a time for that session. This is because `session_write_close()` is automatically called upon script termination so if the first call takes 60 seconds to execute then the other calls have to wait. This is called session locking and is important in the prevention of race conditions.

If your AJAX calls do not need session data then do not open a session in those scripts.

If your AJAX calls do require session data then make sure to `session_write_close()` as soon as you do not need the session array any longer.

Below is an example of how to mitigate session locking:

```
<?php
// some code, blah blah blah

// We need the user_id from the session for this DB query
session_start();

// Cache it into a local variable
$user_id = $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ];

// Close the session because we have what we need
session_write_close();

// Some super long DB query which can take many seconds
// select * from whatever where user_id = $user_id

// provide result to the AJAX call
echo json_encode( $db_results );
```